# OpenCV Won't draw circle - Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

What's wrong with this - why won't it draw the circle in the window I create?

```
    threeDWinName = "3D View"
    cv2.namedWindow(threeDWinName, cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    img2 = cv2.imread('white.png', 0)
    cv2.imshow(threeDWinName,img2)
    cv2.circle(img2, (100,100),100,255,-1)
    cv2.imshow(threeDWinName,img2)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code works for me. I see the file you are reading is called `white.png`, and by loading it with the `0` you are loading it in `grayscale`, so the circle you are drawing is also white. That could be the problem ;)

```
img2 = cv2.imread('black.png', 0)
cv2.circle(img2, (100,100),100,255,-1)
cv2.imwrite('circle.png', img2)
```

[image]

or if you use `img2 = cv2.imread('black.png')`, then you get this:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help again.  Why does the grayscale representation of a blue circle go white?  I gave up on trying to make  a background because I couldn't get the circle draw function work, so figured I'd use my own background image.  Not efficient I know,...

Comment: @Sam Heather - Hey, happy to help. For grayscale images the value between 0 and 255 is a shade of grey, from black to white. For colour images, usually you would pass a tuple of three values, like this `(255,0,0)` This represents the luminousity of each of the channels Blue, Green, and Red (or BGR). But in your case you've only passed a single value, and the function has interpreted it as the value for the first (Blue) channel. If you pass (0,0,255), you'll get a red circle. Try changing the values to generate different colours.